# htaccess/htpasswd in hierarchical folder structure

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder (folder_1) that is protected by htaccess/htpasswd files. Inside that folder is another folder (folder_2) that is protected by another couple of htaccess/htpasswd files.

When a php-script in folder_1 or folder_2 is called, the user has to authenticate herself using the correct username and password as specified in the respective htaccess/htpasswd files. This works as intended.

However, as soon as the php-script in folder_2 tries to refer to another script or a css-file that is located in folder_1, the user must enter username and password for folder_1 as well.

Is there a way to avoid this that does not involve copying scripts and css-files from folder_1 to folder_2?

Regards,
Ralf

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not; as simply enough, any requests from a particular directory use the rules defined in its own htaccess/htpasswd files. However, I can recommend that you put support files in a tertiary folder, so that you don't have to have a copy in each folder (put css and js in a "folder 3" of sorts).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using access rights, see here under "Checking access rights" about half way down the page. The results is only one login required by a user.

http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html

I've spent a half day looking into this as it would be an ideal solution for my staging server.